# vue-cropperjs is not refreshing when adding new photo

Tags: vue.js

I'm using this input for adding new image

```
<input type="file" id="profile_photo_add" ref="profile_photo_add" @change="createProfilePhotoPreviewInAdd"/>

<vue-cropper 
                v-if="urlProfilePreviewAdd"
                ref="cropperAdd" 
                :src="urlProfilePreviewAdd"
                alt="Source Image" 
                :aspectRatio="16/9"
                :initialAspectRatio="16/9" 
                :autoCropArea="1"
                :zoomable="false"/>
```

And this method for creating object url for cropper

```
createProfilePhotoPreviewInAdd(e)
    {
      this.urlProfilePreviewAdd = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
      console.log(this.urlProfilePreviewAdd)
      console.log(this.$refs.cropperAdd)
    }
```

First time when i upload a image, the cropper shows that image, if i'm trying to upload other image, the cropper doesn't refresh.
If i console.log the cropper ref and the urlProfilePreviewAdd i see that urlProfilePreviewAdd is changing but the cropper ref target stays the same as first time.
How to update in real time with the input, the cropper too?
[SS for console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yOLY.jpg)

Take a look to ss for console.logs too here.

Comment: It's probably cause i dont create e new instance of vue-cropperjs and still use the same on, but the quetion is how to create a new instance and use it in that specific div where it is now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the `replace` function on the cropper instance as noted in the [documentation](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#replaceurl-hassamesize)

> Replace the image's src and rebuild the cropper.

```js
setImage(e) {
  this.urlProfilePreviewAdd = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  this.$refs.cropper.replace(this.urlProfilePreviewAdd);
},
```